# Net::SSH::Perl : Received disconnect message: Too many authentication failures for username

Tags: perl, ssh

I am trying to connect to a remote server and run ssh commands in my Perl script. I have provided the correct port, host, username and password. Using the same credentials I can properly login through terminal. When I provide the same in my code I get error response. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
use strict;

use Net::SSH::Perl;

my $hostname = "xxx.zzz.ccc.vvv";
my $username = "username";
my $password = "password";

my $cmd = "aws --version";

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$hostname", debug=>0, port=> 56789);
$ssh->login("$username","$password");
my ($stdout,$stderr,$exit) = $ssh->cmd("$cmd");
print $stdout;
```

Here is the output:

```
Received disconnect message: Too many authentication failures for username
at /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.0/Net/SSH/Perl/AuthMgr.pm line 157.
```

Comment: Does `"password"` contain any metacharacters (`@`, `$`, `\ `, `"`) that need to be escaped inside double quotes?

Comment: @mob yes it does contain an `@` symbol

Comment: Next question: are you escaping the `@` symbol correctly inside double quotes? `$password="qwer@345"` is wrong (will set `$password` to `qwer` and emit a warning if you `use warnings`), it should be `$password="qwer\@345"`, or use single quotes `$password='qwer@345'` .

Comment: @mob That was the problem. It fixed it. Can you post it as an answer? lemme accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your password is specified inside double quotes, and Perl will interpolate scalar and array variables inside double quotes.

```
$password = "qwer@345"; print $password;    #   "qwer"
```

If you use double quotes to enclose a string, you must escape any special characters in that string such as `$`, `@`, `"`, or `\`.

```
$password = "qwer\@345"; print $password;    #   "qwer@345"
```

or use single quotes -- Perl does not do interpolation inside single quotes.

```
$password = 'qwer@345'; print $password;    #   "qwer@345"
```

If you `use warnings` (you always `use warnings`, don't you?), sometimes Perl will warn you when something you write in double quotes might get misinterpreted.